# Qt interfaces class

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

How can I create an interface class, something like this :

```
template<typename file_system_t>
    class ireciver_intervace : public QObject
    {
        public:
        typedef typename file_system_t::file_system_item file_system_item;
    public Q_SLOTS:
        virtual void dataChangeItem(file_system_item *item)=0;
        virtual void removeItem(file_system_item *item)=0;
        virtual void insertItem(file_system_item *item)=0;
    };
```

and derived class

```
class FileItemModel:public QAbstractItemModel ,public ireciver_intervace<file_system>
        {
            Q_OBJECT
        }
```

When I inherit from this class I get an error mentioning ambiguous conversions. I understand this is the right behavior of the compiler, but how can I get interfaces slots for my future classes?  Maybe I must use the `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***QObject subclasses with signal/slot functionality can't be templated.***](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq15-academic.html)

You can simply drop the QObject inheritance of your interface, the rest will be fine. It's no problem to define a (pure) virtual function and then (in the subclass) make a slot out of it by putting it in the `slots` section of your subclass:

```
template<typename file_system_t>
class ireceiver_interface
{
public:
    typedef typename file_system_t::file_system_item file_system_item;

    // pure virtual functions (NO SLOTS!):
    virtual void dataChangeItem(file_system_item *item)=0;
    virtual void removeItem(file_system_item *item)=0;
    virtual void insertItem(file_system_item *item)=0;
};
```

```
class FileItemModel: public QAbstractItemModel,
                     public ireceiver_interface<file_system_t>
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
public slots:
    // implementations (slots):
    virtual void dataChangeItem(file_system_item *item);
    virtual void removeItem(file_system_item *item);
    virtual void insertItem(file_system_item *item);
    ...
}
```

However, the idea of an interface is to define what functions a concrete class has to implement. Here, the interface can't force the subclass to define those functions *as slots*, it can also define them as *non-slot functions*. This minor problem can't be solved. Even if the interface could be a QObject, the subclass could then decide to re-implement those methods as non-slots!

<sub>*Note that you have two typos in your class name: It's **receiver**, not **reciver** and it's **interface**, not **intervace**.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherit from more than one `QObject`. However, both classes you inherit from are `QObjects`.

Some possibilities you could consider are the following:

- Let the class `ireciver_intervace` inherit from `QAbstractItemModel` instead of `QObject`. This way, `FileItemModel` can simply inherit from `ireciver_intervace`. (may not be possible depending on what you want to achieve)
- Use delegation for the `QAbstractItemModel` instead of inheritance.